# float : left and clear : right

Tags: css, css-float

I want to diplay three div like this:

```
[1]    
[2][3]
```

The three div have style: `float: left`
The div 1 have: `clear: right`

Ok I just to put `clear: left` on div `[2]`, but if this div is optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing float: left from div 1

Answer (score 3):

Put `float: left;` on div 2 and 3. Thats it.

Get rid of the rest of your styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/hBrE7/

Comment: @Fozzyuw Thanks, I have one in my answer, but i like yours better

Comment: Opps, I blindly missed your fiddle.  Selective seeing, I suppose.